# Query: select specific fields from specific table

Tags: php, mysql, database, select

I am trying to create a login function that would allow me to specify what table I want to select the data from, and also what fields I want to select.
I have managed to pass the table value to the function, and select data from the desired table, but my tables have different fields. How can I specify in the query it is one table select: user_id, user_first_name, user_password , or if it is the other table select member_id, member_first_name, member_password.

Here is what I have coded so far:

```
public function logIn($id, $password, $table){
    $dataArray = array();
    $t = ($table === 'employers') ? 'employers' : 'members');
    $query = "SELECT user_id, user_first_name, user_password FROM $t";
    $stmt = $this->link->prepare($query);

    if ($stmt->execute())
    {
        $result = $stmt->get_result();
        while($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC))
            { 
            $dbuser_id = $row['user_id'];
            $dbpassword = $row['user_password'];
            $dbuser_first_name = $row['user_first_name'];
            } 
    //and so on...
```

Also, one quick question: Is this a bad programming practice, or should I have 2 login(members, and users)?

Thanks :)

Comment: Instead of just `if ($stmt->execute())` do this `if(!$stmt->execute()){trigger_error("there was an error....".$this->link->error, E_USER_WARNING);}` and get the real error, if one exists.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Thanks for the tip, I was about to do error checking after.

Comment: You could use a `switch` on the `$table` then set the table and columns you want as variables and put them into the query.

Comment: @chris85 Hmmm, yeah, that might work.. I was thinking how there is a way to specify the table there could be a way to do it for the fields as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Single Responsibility Principle in programming is intended to prevent things like this from happening - the goal is for one class/function to have one responsibility, rather than having to manage 2 (or potentially more) as you have here. In short, it is a bad programming practice and you should have 2 login functions like you said. After making 2 different functions, a `switch` statement might help to check the case of a member logging in versus a user.

Note: There are exceptions to this. However, in your case, it would make more sense to separate the two.

Here is a link to further explain **SRP** and **SOLID** design principles:

[Single Responsibility Principle on TutsPlus](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/solid-part-1-the-single-responsibility-principle--net-36074)